# WPF WebBrowser in Window Flash Scrollbar issue

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control

I am hosting a flash application inside a WebBrowser inside a Window that has set width and height. The issue is there is no scrolling and half of the Flash application cannot be accessed. Is there anyway to circumvent this issue?